# A question about conditional heteroscedasticity

Tags: regression, time-series, self-study, autocorrelation, heteroscedasticity

Consider the linear model regression (matricial form):
$$y= X\beta + \epsilon$$

I am reading the book Econometrics, by Fumio Hayashi. Considere the following:

> Assumption 1.4 states that the $n\times n$ matrix of conditional second moments $E[\epsilon \epsilon' | X]$ is spherical, that is, proportional to the identity matrix. Without the assumption, each element of the $n \times n$ matrix is in general a nonlinear function of $X$. If the error is not (conditionally) homoskedastic, the values of the diagonal elements of $E[\epsilon \epsilon' | X]$ are not the same, and if there is correlation in the error term between observations (the case of serial correlation for time-series models), the values of the off-diagonal elements are not zero.

I'm trying to find an example of a time series for the part of the quote mentioned above:

> if there is correlation in the error term between observations (the case of serial correlation for time-series models), the values of the off-diagonal elements are not zero.

I even tried an AR(1):
$$y_t = \beta x_t + \epsilon_t, \quad x_t = y_{t-1}, \quad \epsilon_t \sim IID(0,1) $$
By definition $cov(\epsilon_t, \epsilon_{t-1})=0$. However, perhaps when we condition $X$ it is not null:
$$
\begin{aligned}
cov(\epsilon_t, \epsilon_{t-1}|X) &= cov(y_t - \beta y_{t-1} \, ,\, y_{t-1} - \beta y_{t-2}|X)\\
& =cov(y_t, y_{t-1}|X) - cov(y_t , \beta y_{t-2}|X) - cov(\beta y_{t-1}, y_{t-1}|X)+ cov(\beta y_{t-1}, \beta y_{t-2}|X)\\
& =cov(y_t, y_{t-1}|X) - \beta cov(y_t , y_{t-2}|X) - \beta cov( y_{t-1}, y_{t-1}|X)+ \beta^2 cov( y_{t-1}, y_{t-2}|X)\\
& =\gamma(1|X) - \beta \gamma(2|X) - \beta \gamma( 0|X)+ \beta^2 \gamma( 1|X) 
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\gamma(h|X)$ is the conditional autocovariance function. The unconditional is given by:
$$\gamma(h)=\beta^h \frac{1}{1-\beta^2} $$
I don't know if I'm on the right path or I have to think of some other example.

Help!

Comment: That's not an AR(1) model for the error terms.  Use $\epsilon_t = \rho \epsilon_{t-1}+\delta_t$ to generate such a model and let $y_t =\beta x_t + \epsilon_t.$

Comment: Is this process an AR(1) model with AR(1) error? What is the classification of this type of process called?

Comment: What you want is what whuber suggested. The model is called a time series regression where the error term is AR(1). This model fits in to what you said in your quote about off diagonal elements being non-zero. The AR(1) time series model ( which is what you were working on. that's where the response is AR(1). In whuber's suggestion, the error term is AR(1) ) does not. Make sure to understand the difference between the two models. The names are kind of similar but that's as far as the similarity goes.